# Problemas com FluentNhibernate na hospedagem

Tags: c#

Desenvolvi um website em c# que ainda esta em fase de testes, utilizando .NetFramework 4.0 e MVC 4

Estou utilizando Nhibernate e FluentNhibernate para mapear as minhas entidades.

O site funciona perfeitamente em qualquer computador que eu configurar o IIS.

Mas contratei uma hospedagem que é a UolHost, e estou enfrentando problemas com a mensagem abaixo ao acessar um controller que estabelece conexão com o banco de dados:

> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

É a primeira vez que estou hospedando um site neste tipo de ambiente

Se eu depurar o meu projeto em meu computador, apontando para o banco de dados da hospedagem da UolHost funciona também, ou seja o meu WebConfig até então está correto

Ficarei grato pela ajuda

Comment: Vc conseguiu resolver esse problema ? Como fez ?

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente este host não está configurado para operar em Full Trust Level. Lei sobre [Security Changes in the .NET Framework 4][1] e [Security Transparent Code, Level 2][2] no MSDN para maiores informações.

Há um meio de fazer o NHibernate operar em Medium Trust Level e requer algumas configurações adicionais. Dê uma olhada nos links abaixo:

http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/update-nhibernate-32-and-medium-trust.html

http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/nhibernate-32-and-medium-trust.html

http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/run-in-medium-trust.html